# How do you make 3d features from survey point data in arcGIS 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, 3d, survey-analyst

I have survey point data brought into ArcGIS using Survey Analyst Extension. I have created my 2D shapefiles of the cross-sections, thalwegs, and roadways but I can not get it to populate the zfield from the point data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a ShapeZ shapefile.

can be done with GeoWizards Free Functions
Point To Point Z (M)
http://www.ian-ko.com/

Answer (score 0):

When you load data in arcgis you assign the z value and the vertical crs

Edited: for comment - I have not used survey analyst.

However if you follow this process it might help you find the corresponding process for survey analyst.

I would think that SA would have a process for 3d point creation. that said...

In arccatalog if you right click on the folder you want to create a new shape file in> select new> shapefile.

The dialog should default to the point feature type. Select the check box at the bottom for z values. Then just give it a name and select edit for the spatial reference. Complete the xy coordinate system tab and then select the z coordinate system tab with the appropriate system OK to complete.

Comment: what do you mean by vertical crs? Sorry I am a new user in GIS.

Comment: see edit above.